# SSIS Package Fails Moving Documents to SP via UNC path

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, document-library, integration

I have an SSIS package that moves files to SharePoint using unc path `\\intranet.domain.local\library\`. The package was failing until I logged onto the SQL Server, browsed the site http://intranet.domain.local/library/ and clicked on Open With Windows Explorer. How can I maintain this unc connection without constantly connecting and browsing the site from the SQL server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This guy (http://whitepages.unlimitedviz.com/2010/12/unc-path-naming-for-files-stored-on-sharepoint-2/) was having the same issue.  His fix was to change the UNC path a bit:

```
\\ServerURL\DavWWWRoot\Site1Name\Site2Name\LibraryName\FolderName
```

So:

```
\\intranet.domain.local\DavWWWRoot\Library
```

Play with that a bit until you have it working in Windows Explorer, then use that in SSIS.

Comment: This didn't permanently resolve my issue. I still had to logoff my RDP session, log back on and reconnect to sharepoint using Windows Explorer to reset my web dav connection.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a permission issue. Make sure that the process identity SSIS is using has the appropriate permissions to access SharePoint.